# VPC endpoint in Cloudformation - Endpoint type (Gateway) does not match available service types ([Interface])

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-api-gateway

I'm trying to create a VPC endpoint for API Gateway in Cloudformation, but got this error:

```
Endpoint type (Gateway) does not match available service types ([Interface]).
```

The template below is placed inside the Resources section:

```
  executeApiEndpoint:
    Type: AWS::EC2::VPCEndpoint
    Properties:
      PolicyDocument:
        Version: '2012-10-17'
        Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Principal: "*"
            Action:
              - "execute-api:Invoke"
              - "execute-api:ManageConnections"
            Resource:
              - "arn:aws:execute-api:*:*:*"
      RouteTableIds:
        - !Ref privateRouteTable
      ServiceName: !Sub com.amazonaws.${AWS::Region}.execute-api
      VpcId: !Ref pubPrivateVPC
```

This one doesn't work either:

```
  executeApiEndpoint:
    Type: AWS::EC2::VPCEndpoint
    Properties:
      PolicyDocument:
        Version: '2012-10-17'
        Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Principal: "*"
            Action:
              - "execute-api:*"
            Resource:
              - "*"
      RouteTableIds:
        - !Ref privateRouteTable
      ServiceName: !Sub com.amazonaws.${AWS::Region}.execute-api
      VpcId: !Ref pubPrivateVPC
```

However, this block (comes from a template) was able to be executed without any error:

```
  s3Endpoint:
    Type: AWS::EC2::VPCEndpoint
    Properties:
      PolicyDocument:
        Version: 2012-10-17
        Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Principal: "*"
            Action:
              - "s3:*"
            Resource:
              - "*"
      RouteTableIds:
        - !Ref privateRouteTable
      ServiceName: !Sub com.amazonaws.${AWS::Region}.s3
      VpcId: !Ref pubPrivateVPC
```

What is going wrong here?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You must also specify the [VpcEndpointType property](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-ec2-vpcendpoint.html#cfn-ec2-vpcendpoint-vpcendpointtype) on the `AWS::EC2::VPCEndpoint` resource to be `Interface` for interface typed VPC endpoints to work. The default is "Gateway", which only works for S3 and DynamoDB VPC endpoints.

The reason your solution works with S3 as endpoint is because that `VpcEndpointType` property has "Gateway" as default value (suitable for S3).